# cmd: Command failed with exit code 1, Error : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon')

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

So i have found a few questions that start the same, but none of them apply to my exact situation, as such neither do the answers.
i'm using cordova in VS studio 2015 and everything was fine 1 hour ago.
But for some reason the builds fail when deploying to device(or emulator) now, even though i have changed nothing in my code!
(i added 1 small IF statement, that i have since rolled back)

The error i get is :

> cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 FriendFinder    C:\uni
>   project\FriendFinder\FriendFinder\FriendFinder\ERROR building one of
>   the platforms 1

reading full debug log, and finding the first instance of the word "failed" revealed it to be here :

> C:\uni
>   project\FriendFinder\FriendFinder\FriendFinder\platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:29:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon'
>   with value '@drawable/icon'). (TaskId:11)

All the fixes i've found say to remove that line, or use a different icon, or something similar. Yet i have never set any icons, nor do i plan to for some time, and the manifest is un-editable(it's re-generated each build by VS)

I'm truly baffled, because i effectively haven't changed anything since it was working fine 1h ago.

Comment: Is it possible the space in "uni project" is somehow causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out visual studio had deleted the resources from the project, all by itself.
Creating a new blank Cordova app and copying the generated ones across to this project fixed the problem.